# Service Cloud + Case Assignment + ListView Refresh = Trouble?

Tags: service-cloud-console, list-view, refresh

first of all: Yes I know, List Viewing user Id needs to be Case Owner Id in order for the standard service cloud refresh list to work.

What I got to work is this:

- Setup Email 2 Case
- Support Settings => Make me the default case owner if assignment fails
- Open Service Console, got to list: 'myCases' (Only shows my cases)
- Send an Email to Email2Case
- Voila: List does refresh

What does not work:

- Custom Settings => Default User X is Case Owner
- Using Assignment Rules to determine Case Owner => User Y
- Send Email to Email2Case Address
- Open Service Cloud, got to list: 'myCases' as User Y
- send an Email To Email2Case

=> No Refresh

I am really at loss. Can somebody confirm/deny that Assignment Rules do affect the standard refresh behaviour?

Kind Regards,
Sz

Comment: I have opened a case with Salesforce for the issue. They did not confirm yet as to whether assignment rules are intended to trigger the list refresh or not. Will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce could identify the issue: We failed to ensure the viewing users' profiles have at least Read Permission on Push Topic Object.

Sz